# .NET UDP Multicast reception

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, udpclient

I am occassionally seeing a packet being received twice by my udp multicast reciever. I set up the multicast client as follows:

```
private static void setupUdpMulticastClient()
    {
        //IPEndPoint ipRXEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,multicastPort);
        IPEndPoint ipRXEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(emulatorIpaddr), multicastPort);
        udpMulticastClient = new UdpClient();
        udpMulticastClient.Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        udpMulticastClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpMulticastClient.Client.Bind(ipRXEnd);
    }
```

The emulatorIpaddr is a 192.x.x.x address.

The receiver looks as follows:

```
public static void MulticastSetBeginReceive()
    {
        //IPAddress ipSSDP = IPAddress.Parse(multicastIP);
        IPAddress ipSSDP = IPAddress.Parse(emulatorIpaddr);
        IPEndPoint ipRXEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipSSDP, multicastPort);
        UdpState udpListener = new UdpState();
        udpListener.e = ipRXEnd;

        if (udpMulticastClient == null)
        { setupUdpMulticastClient();}

        udpListener.u = udpMulticastClient;
        udpMulticastClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(MulticastReceiveCallback), udpListener);
    }
```

It seems to trigger the async callback 2 times on occassion. For sake of completeness,
here is the callback code:

```
public static void MulticastReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
            IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

            if (u.Client != null)
            {
                Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
                string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                string from = e.ToString();
                string to = ((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e.ToString();
                msgReceiver(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), from, to, receiveString);
            }
            if (running)
                MulticastSetBeginReceive();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Debug(ex.Message);
            log.Debug(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I am running Windows 7 and .Net 4.

Does anyone see an issue with the code, or know of an issue with .NET or win 7, that would result in such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For receivestring, use 
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Count())

instead of ASCII